# How test a void method into Service class, with Mockito?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, testing, mockito

I need to make pass all my test and to reach a complete code coverage for all classes of my project.

I created a Repository, Service and Controller class.

I need to test all single method into these classes.

I have these classes:
1) ApplicationController     with     ApplicationControllerTest
2) UserService     with     UserServiceTest
3) UserRepository     with     UserRepositoryTest

This is the controller:

```
 @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/")
    @SessionAttributes("user")
    public class ApplicationWebController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private FundService fundService;

    @PostMapping("/save-user")
    public String saveUser(User user, Model model) {
        final User presentUsername = 
    userService.getUserByUsername(user.getUsername());
        if (presentUsername == null) {
            userService.insertNewUser(user);
            if((user.getUsername()).equals("admin")) {
                userService.updateRoleToAdmin(user.getId());
            }
    }
```

Here I insert a new User; if User.username is equal to "admin" then I update the field "role" with userService.updateRoleToAdmin(user.getId())

This is the JUnit test for controller:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = ApplicationWebController.class)
public class ApplicationWebControllerTest {

@Autowired
private WebClient webClient;

@MockBean
private UserService userService;

@Test
public void test_whenInsertedUserIsAdmin_DoUpdateOnRole() throws 
Exception {

User userInserted = new User(1L, "admin", "password", 1);       

mvc.perform(post("/save-user")
        .param("id", "1")
        .param("username", "admin")
        .param("password", "password")
        .param("role", "1"));

if (userInserted.getUsername() == "admin") {
    verify(userService).updateRoleToAdmin(1L);
}
}
}
```

this test correctly pass.

Now I have the Service class and the relative test class

This is the Service class

```
@Service
public class UserService {

private UserRepo userRepo;

public void updateRoleToAdmin(Long id) {
    userRepo.updateRoleToAdmin(id);
}
}
```

This class also must be tested and this is the JUnit class for the Service

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UserServiceTest {

@Mock
private UserRepo userRepo;

@InjectMocks
private UserService userService;

@Test
public void test_updateRoleToAdmin() {
//I DON'T KNOW HOW WRITE HERE
        //I NEED TO TEST THE RESPECTIVE METHOD IN SERVICE CLASS
        //THE METHOD IN userRepo IS A VOID METHOD 
}
}
```

These are my Repository classes (class and JUnit test)

```
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

@Modifying(flushAutomatically = true, clearAutomatically = true)
@Transactional
@Query("update User u set u.role = 2 where u.id = :userid")
void updateRoleToAdmin(@Param("userid") Long id);

}
```

The test for the Repo class:

```
@Test
public void test_UpdateRoleToAdmin() {
User user = new User(null, "admin", "password", 1);
User saved = userRepo.save(user);
userRepo.updateRoleToAdmin(saved.getId());
User found = userRepo.findByUsername("admin");
assertThat(found.getRole()).isEqualTo(2);
}
```

also, this test correctly pass

Now I must write a test into UserServiceTest JUnit test class.

I don't know what should I do, because it's a void method and I can't use  when(method).thenReturn(..) and the following Assertion

I must have a Code Coverage of 100% for all my classes and without test the method "UserService.updateRoleToAdmin(Long id)" I can't reach it.

Please help, because I don't know how to test a void method there.

Thank you.
I need to make pass all my test and to reach a complete code coverage for all classes of my project.

I created a Repository, Service and Controller class.

I need to test all single method into these classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should test what is happening inside of the SUT method. You already have the repo mocked so just verify behaviour in the test:

```
@Test
public void shouldUpdateRoleToAdmin() {
    // When
    userService.updateRoleToAdmin(anyLong());

    // Then
    verify(userRepo, times(1)).updateRoleToAdmin(anyLong()); 
}
```

after you have invoked the method with a certain `id`.

Comment: I tried, but the test doesn't pass. Fails with:

                  Wanted but not invoked:
userRepo.updateRoleToAdmin(1L);
-> at com.crowdfunding.service.UserServiceTest.test_updateRoleToAdmin(UserServiceTest.java:28)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

I tried two ways:
1) 
    verify(userRepo, times(1)).updateRoleToAdmin(anyLong());
2)
    User user = new User(1L, "admin", "password", 1);
    verify(userRepo, times(1)).updateRoleToAdmin(user.getId());

Comment: Did you invoke the service method before verify?

Comment: Now I add     userService.updateRoleToAdmin(anyLong());
    and works!!!  Thank you very much